# How to get string between parthenses in regex?

Tags: regex

I need help on getting a regex expression to get a string between ( )

`Use your email (test@gmail.com) to login.`

I need a regex expression that would get the email out. I can't seem to do it. Is it because of the ( )?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the program you're writing your regex for you'll have to use appropriate escaping. For example, with sed:

```
ts@xenon:~> echo 'Use your email (test@gmail.com) to login.' | sed -e 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/'
test@gmail.com
ts@xenon:~>
```

In this case, the backslashes will escape the parentheses after them into metacharacters that extract the matched string between them into the metavariable `\1` while the parentheses not preceded by a backslash will be matched literally.